# Weird Java's typesafety not working for collections

Tags: java, java-8

```
  public static <T> List<T> toArray(JSONArray array) {
        if(array == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        List<T> o = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0, l = array.length(); i < l; i++) {
            o.add((T) array.get(i));
        }

        return o;
    }

    public static void test() {
        List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add("Product");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("key", values);
        List<Long> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test = toArray((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("key"));
        System.out.println(test);
    }
```

The above code allows storing `String` values in a `List<Long>`, totally absurd. Any help much appreciated?

Comment: Do you understand why it's warning you about unchecked casts?

Comment: @AndyTurner i didn't get any warning. My doubt is we declared a List<Long> then how it holds List<String>

Comment: Generics provide type safety if your code (and all your libraries) compile without any of those typesafety warnings. Your `(T)` cast is unchecked, which means: the compiler will pretend you know what you're doing but doesn't actually verify that the object is of type `T`.

Comment: @kannanrbk: then you didn't look closely. Your code doesn't compile without warnings.

Comment: Unless you have warnings disabled, you will get a warning from this code.

Comment: Unfortunately, some IDEs ship with bad defaults regarding compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
o.add((T) array.get(i));
```

will generate an unchecked cast warning.

An unchecked cast is a cast where the compiler can't insert a `checkcast` bytecode instruction to check that it's really an instance of the type you're casting to. It can't do that here, because it doesn't know what `T` "is".

You are simply doing something unsafe. You will be warned about this, unless you've suppressed the warnings (which is not a great idea, because you then aren't told about doing something unsafe).

That's just the way Java works.

---

You can do this safely by passing in a `Function<Object, T>` (or, more generally, `Function<Object, ? extends T>`) as a parameter:

```
public static <T> List<T> toArray(JSONArray array, Function<Object, ? extends T> checker) {
  // ...
  o.add(checker.apply(array.get(i)));
  // ...
}
```

Now, the responsibility to ensure it is a `T` is delegated to `checker`: you can call this method something like:

```
test = toArray((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("key"), Long.class::cast);
```

and this will fail if the element isn't a `Long`.